# How to create dynamic instances of a class

Tags: delphi

I want to be able to create instances of a class without having to declare them each as objects.
A simple example. I have a program that registers dogs for a dog show. Every time the user clicks add it should create a new instance of the TDog class. How do I do this?

My attemp statically:

```
//clsDog_u
type
 TDog = class(TObject)
 private
  fName : string;
 public
  constructor Create(Name);
  function Get_Name():string;
end;

implementation
//I think you guys knows what goes here ;)

//------------Main Form---------------
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, clsDog;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    objDog: tDog;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Name: string;
begin
  name := InputBox('', 'please enter in name:', 'Doggo1');
  objDog := tDog.Create(name);
  ShowMessage(objDog.Get_Name + ' has been added to the dog show.');

end;

end.
```

Comment: Use a `TObjectList<TDog>`.

Comment: The most obvious way is: put all the dogs into an `Array` - a very basic concept of programming. More comfort comes with Delphi's well-known `TList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great time to use a [`TObjectList<TDog>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList).

To get started, you can let this object be a field of the form class:

```pascal
type
  TDog = class
    Name: string;
    Breed: string;
    Born: TDateTime;
    constructor Create(const AName, ABreed: string; const ABorn: TDateTime);
  end;

type
  TDogSimForm = class(TForm)
    btnAddDog: TButton;
    eName: TEdit;
    eBreed: TEdit;
    dtpBorn: TDateTimePicker;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddDogClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDogs: TObjectList<TDog>;
  public
  end;
```

and

```pascal
procedure TDogSimForm.btnAddDogClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDogs.Add(
    TDog.Create(eName.Text, eBreed.Text, dtpBorn.DateTime)
  )
end;

procedure TDogSimForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDogs := TObjectList<TDog>.Create;
end;

procedure TDogSimForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FDogs);
end;

{ TDog }

constructor TDog.Create(const AName, ABreed: string; const ABorn: TDateTime);
begin
  Name := AName;
  Breed := ABreed;
  Born := ABorn;
end;
```